# How to append a list to class object?

Tags: python, list, class

*emphasized text*I want to append two lists together if the difference between the values in the new appended list will be 1. For example, if my second list is [8, 7, 6] then I would add it to my first list while removing all the numbers from the second list.

```
num = [10, 9]
current_nums = [8, 7, 6]
#after appending
num = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6] 
current_nums = #empty
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
def add(self, num):
    if len(self.current_nums) > 0:
        num.append(self.current_nums)
        difference = []
        for i in range(1, len(self.num)):
            difference.append(self.num[i] - self.num[i-1])
        
        res = difference.count(difference[0]) == len(difference)
        if res == True:
            self.current_nums.pop()
```

When I try to append the first list to the second list I get an AttributeError: type object 'Board' has no attribute 'append'. How can I append a list to a class object?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Also see https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1):

```
class ExtendList:
"""class with methods to extend first list by second list and empty the second list
Attributes:
  list1: first list
  list2: second list
"""

    def __init__(self, list1: list, list2: list) -> None:
        self.list1: list = list1
        self.list2: list = list2

    def extend_list1_and_empty_list2(self) -> None:
        """extend list 1 and empty list 2"""
        self.list1.extend(self.list2)
        self.empty_list2()

    def empty_list2(self) -> None:
        """empty list 2"""
        self.list2 = []



list_obj: ExtendList = ExtendList([10, 9], [8, 7, 6])

list_obj.extend_list1_and_empty_list2()

print(list_obj.list1)
print(list_obj.list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
list1 = [10, 9]
list2 = [8, 7, 6]
list3 = list1
kt = True
for i in range(0, len(list2)):
    list1.append(list2[i])
for i in range(0, len(list2)-1):
    if list1[i] - list1[i+1] != 1:
        kt = False
if kt:
    list2=[0]
else:
    list1 = list3
```

Firstly, you want to add list2 to list1. It is quite easy then. In this program, I use a for loop and an "append" function.

Secondly, you want to check if the difference between the values is one. You can do this using a for loop and a boolean variable. If the difference is not one then you want to return the old list1. That's why the list3 is there.